# re-login cookie (will it be secure enough)

Tags: php, cookies, pdo

So my website is setup to destroy sessions after 30 mins and i want to throw in a remember me option for users.

Essentially it would work like this, please excuse me for psuedo code

```
setcookie("sitename[id]", $userid, time()+60*60*24*30);
setcookie("sitename[pass]", $hasedandsaltedpassword);
setcookie("sitename[username]", $username);
```

So when a user is auto logged out I then check the cookie for usability

```
$count = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = :name AND id = :id AND pass = :pass");
    $count->bindParam(":name", $_COOKIE["sitename"]["username"]);
    $count->bindParam(":id", $_COOKIE["sitename"]["id"]);
    $count->bindParam(":pass", $_COOKIE["sitename"]["pass"]);
    $count->execute();
    $count = $count->rowCount();
```

and if the row count is above 0 but not greater than 1 then I set new session variables for them.

Comment: I think that's not safe, because apparently that doesn't leave you a way to invalidate the cookies if you need to. If an authorized user gets access to the cookie, the only way of logging him out would be changing the user password, would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work, but is not particularly secure.  You are just comparing the pre-hashed password against your DB...so since the password does not ever change, you can essentially be giving anyone with access to the cookie the ability to log in anytime they want just by modifying the cookie data.

I would suggest adding another table to the DB (or expanding the current user table) to include the IP address (or browser string + IP...all hashed...or whatever unique info you can about the specific user's actual computer) of the computer that was being "remembered" and likewise a field for when that remembrance should expire.  That way you can do two extra things: 1) expire the login early if needed and 2) validate that the cookie has not been extended.  Even then it is not technically "secure" but you will be MUCH closer.

Comment: actually my current user table has two extra fields i could use for unique salted hashes and if remember me is set.

Answer (score 0):

That's it...
But you need to check bellow things
-> If user has select remember me, than only you have to check this condition
-> If you is logged out successfully you don't need to check it again